# Как лучше хранить информацию о правах пользователей?

Tags: архитектура, проектирование, любой-язык

Приветствую. Предположим, у меня есть своё API с методами `users.get`, `users.edit`, `users.ban`, и другими. Есть также какие-то категории пользователей, например, обычный пользователь, модератор или администратор.

Вопрос заключается в способе оптимального и удобного хранения информации (в базе данных) о том, какие методы может вызывать конкретная категория пользователей. Например, обычным пользователям доступен лишь метод `users.get`, в то время как администраторам доступны все методы.

Я рассматривал вариант хранить число в базе данных, и использовать его двоичное представление: 1-й двоичный разряд отвечает за возможность вызова `users.get`, 2-й - `users.edit` и так далее. Недостатком данного подхода является ограниченность типа int - не более 64 битов, в то время как количество методов может превысить это число.

Буду благодарен за ваши предложения. Наилучшими вариантами будут те, которые позволят строить запросы к базе данных вида: `выбрать такие типы пользователей, которым доступен метод M`.

Comment: [RBAC](https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Управление_доступом_на_основе_ролей) ?

Comment: @defrag, и что? Там нет конкретного примера реализации поля `Permissions`. Там приводится общая концепция, которая у меня есть и так.